# Cronjob stopped executing

Tags: cron

I used the crontab before but cannot get any command running anymore.

I am editing directly via `crontab -e` and testing with simple commands like

```
* * * * * echo "hello there" >> /Users/myUsername/Desktop/test.txt
```

Running this command `ps -ef | grep cron | grep -v grep` gives me this output:

```
  0   270     1   0  6Sep20 ??         0:00.61 /usr/sbin/cron
```

Today is 22Sep20. Did the crontab stop running?

My shell is zsh on MacOS.

Comment: hi, `crontab` executes as root, so you might need `-a` to see all the processes

Comment: What does `crontab -l` return?

Comment: @Dominik crontab -l returns  * * * * * echo "hello there" > /Users/myUsername/Desktop/test.txt (plus a new line in the end)

Comment: Which means it's still running which was your question right?

Comment: @IronMan where or how should I use -a ? Thanks for your help

Comment: @Dominik ah okay. I didn't know this proves that the cronjob is still running. But do you have any idea why I cannot get any command working? I tried a lot with simple commands like the one I posted in the question.

Answer (score 0):

On MacOS run `crontab -l` to list all installed cron scripts
or `crontab -l -u [user]` for another user.

Your `* * * * *` syntax means it's running every minute and that looks all fine to me. [Check syntax here](https://crontab.guru/#*_*_*_*_*)